# Targeting elements in a jQuery Dialog, Why must use this as context

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I find that when I am trying to target an element in a jQuery Dialog, I must do something like

```
$("#elemInDialog", this).val()
                   ^
```

I found that this only occurs in my simple code seen http://jiewmeng.kodingen.com/test/jquery-autocomplete.html or http://jsfiddle.net/28GMT/ (in jsFiddle or jsbin, the auto complete doesn't work even, but it works in my hosted version) what did I do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have at least one typo in there:

This line:

```
$("#txtArea").val( $("#txtArea").val() + "\n" + $("#txtUrl").val() );
```

should be:

```
$("#txtArea").val( $("#txtArea").val() + "\n" + $("#txtURL").val() );
```

With that fix, things seem to work okay for me, as far as I can tell?